# Increment string in Textview each time class is called

Tags: android

I need to know if I can increment a string in another class. The class is called within an onclick method and each time the button is clicked I want the text to show the next string. Is this possible, if so I would appreciate any guidance on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can!  Just create a getter and a setter method within your class.

```
public class Foo() {
...
private String fooString;

  public void setFooString() {
    fooString = fooString + "my new string";
  }

  public String getFooString() {
    return fooString;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I highly appreciate it. Do I need to include both these methods in both classes?

Comment: According to the performance advice in the android developer guide you should use static over getter/setter...

Comment: @Raj No.  Your other class just needs a `Foo` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A {
    public static String blub = "my string";
}

public class B {
    /**
     * Called when the button is clicked.
     */
    public void myOnClickMethod() {
        A.blub += " add this, too";
    }
}
```